# Styling Encoded Text In Doxygen-Generated HTML

Tags: c#, doxygen

I'm generating some API documentation from C# code using Doxygen.

XML comments look like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Some summary text.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Some remarks.
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="type">Type param</param>
/// <param name="id">ID param</param>
/// <response code="200"> OK</response>
/// <response code="400"> Bad Request</response>
/// <response code="500"> Internal Server Error</response>
```

Doxygen-generated HTML for the response code lines looks like this:

```
<p>&lt;response code="200"&gt; OK&lt;/response&gt; &lt;response code="400"&gt; Bad Request&lt;/response&gt; &lt;response code="500"&gt; Internal Server Error&lt;/response&gt; </p>
```

So the response code lines render in the generated page like this:

```
<response code="200"> OK</response> <response code="400"> Bad Request</response> <response code="500"> Internal Server Error</response>
```

When I want them to render like this:

```
<response code="200"> OK</response>
<response code="400"> Bad Request</response>
<response code="500"> Internal Server Error</response>
```

We can't change the way we're formatting the response codes in the XML comments, because our Swagger tool relies on this format.

- I can't use an alias, because it can't do text matches. It has to be something like \response or @response.
- I tried inserting some breaks using custom CSS, but that doesn't work since we're dealing with encoded text.
- I also tried forcing it to render as HTML5 using a custom HTML header, but that made no difference either.

Comment: Is there an authoritative  text that defines the `<response>` tag, at the moment doxygen does not recognize it as t is not a tag defined in the C# standard Ecma-334.

Comment: @albert I don't think so.  It's just a custom tag that's displayed in the Swagger UI for the service.  We don't want to tweak them for Doxygen because (1) it causes them to be ignored or displayed incorrectly in Swagger, and (2) even if they work in Swagger, we'd have to update them in many places.  A solution where Doxygen can deal with them as-is is preferable.

Comment: From the updated description I don't get what would be acceptable for you. Is an `ALIASES` like `response{2}=\htmlonly <response code="\1">\2</response>` and thus a call like `\response{200,OK}` acceptable?

Comment: If I understand aliases correctly, defining an alias like response="something" means Doxygen will look for instances of "@response" in the input file and replace them with the text "something".  The input file actually contains "<response ...", so the alias doesn't map to it.  Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Doxygen has no mechanism the define `ALIASES` or similar in the form of `<...> ... </...>`

Comment: Thinking about the problem, I think it might be solvable by means of an `INPUT_FILTER` or `FILTER_PATTERNS` here you could replace the `<respones... </respone>` by e.g. `\htmlonly <response... </response> \endhtmlonly`

Comment: I assume that the swagger UI uses the original file , is this correct,? I the later case  I think, regarding the filters, maybe it would be even better to transform `<respones... </respone>` to `\retval` with the code as first argument and the description as second argument, so the response is visible in the doxygen HTML documentation.

Comment: Original file as in the .cs source file?  Yes.  I appreciate the suggestions.  I will experiment with these.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that <response> is not recognized as a valid [xml command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/xmlcmds.html) by doxygen. But you can try to add an [alias](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html#custcmd_simple) to your doxygen configuration which converts <response> to an output format of your choice.

Comment: I tried that, but forgot to mention it.  I updated my original post.